# Image files aren't recognized when changing a html file to page.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I want to create a drupal theme base on a static web template. after googleing I've found out that I should set up a `.info` file and also put my header in the `html.tpl.php` and body in `page.tpl.php` and so on.
I change index.html file into `page.tpl.php`, but the image in the site aren't recognized by drupal(although the index.html worked correctly).
It seem to me that drupal should show the page exactly same as static version because I have't added any code into the page ( in order to change the static version into the dynamic one ).
if so, how can I find the problem.
Thanks

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rgpars-custom.js"></script>
```

=====>

.info file:

```
    scripts[] = js/modernizr.js
    scripts[] = js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
    scripts[] = js/rgpars-custom.js
```

html.tpl.php file :

```
    <head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
      <?php print $head; ?>
      <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
      <?php print $styles; ?>
      <?php print $scripts; ?>
    </head>
```

Comment: can you come your code here? `index.html` and `page.tpl.php`?

Comment: Thanks @zhilevan For your reply, the code is too long to come here but I think the problem stem from javascript and they are not work properly. I've edited the post and add some of my script.

Comment: I dont think the problem is about js,can u tell me where did you put`html.tpl.php` exactly ?

Comment: yes you are right I have checked it before and it seems that the problem is somewhere else. sorry @zhilevan I couldn't find my post in the my menu(even in the deleted post) so I thought that it has been deleted I duplicated the post in stackoverflow site. if you let me I delete this post. I completed the post in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260438/after-changing-website-template-into-drupal-images-dont-load

Comment: I suggest edit your question here and follow it here because drupalstackexchange is only for drupal maybe another person in future will have problem like you and search here to find solution for her/his problem, I think the main problem is `bad pathing` in your job, bad path in `image src`

Comment: @MohammadYousefi, how are you generating image? if you are creating content from admin, then you need to set `full html` as text format of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images (ie. your *img* directory) are in your theme directory, use something like `<img src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme(); ?>/img/works/works-full8.jpg" />` to include them.

If they are in your *sites/default/files* directory, use `<img src="/sites/default/files/img/works/works-full8.jpg" />`.

If they are in your site root, use `<img src="/img/works/works-full8.jpg" />`